# Fight in which Mike Tyson knocked out opponent with first punch?

Tags: boxing, match-identification

I remember once seeing a clip in which a young Mike Tyson knocked out his opponent with the very first punch of the fight (or round).

It was an unusual knockout because he hit him in the top of the head. As soon as the bell rang, Tyson charged towards his opponent, jumped a little and punched the guy right above the forehead and he crumpled to the ground.

What fight was that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this fight? Mike Tyson vs Marvis Frazier on July 26, 1986.

He landed a few punches though.

Comment: This was, according to Wikipedia, the quickest fight of Tyson's professional career, so it's almost certainly the right answer. OP most likely just misremembers how many punches Tyson threw.